# How to hide column in filteringtable vaadin 7?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7, vaadin6

I have 5 columns in my table, and how is it possible to make one of the columns invisible? is it any standard approach for that, or maybe, can I use css for that?

Answer (score 3):

You need to allow column collapsing in your table

```
table.setColumnCollapsingAllowed(true);
```

After that, you can collapse or hide any column

```
table.setColumnCollapsed("columnId", true);
```

An example:

```
FilterTable table = new FilterTable("The Brightest Stars");

// Define two columns for the built-in container
table.addContainerProperty("Name", String.class, null);
table.addContainerProperty("Mag",  Float.class, null);

// Allow column collapsing
table.setColumnCollapsingAllowed(true);

// Hide column "Name"
table.setColumnCollapsed("Name", true);
```

Comment: but no, it doesnt work) I mean user still can make it visible) And user shouldnt be able to make it visible

Answer (score 1):

In case you just don't want to show them at all, use [setVisibleColumns](https://vaadin.com/api/7.5.10/com/vaadin/ui/Table.html#setVisibleColumns%28java.lang.Object...%29) on the Table:

> ```
> public void setVisibleColumns(java.lang.Object... visibleColumns)
> ```
>
> Sets the array of visible column property id:s.
>
> The columns are show in the order of their appearance in this array.
>
> Parameters:
>
> `visibleColumns` - the Array of shown property id:s.

(also `setContainerDataSource`) allows passing the visisible columns)

Comment: yes, but I need to have it in the table, because I use it when I double click on one of the records...

Comment: and if it's not in the table, so, I can use this value for further processing

Comment: is it possible to use css for example for that?

Comment: @vlcod why not use a proper container (e.g. BeanItemContainer)?